# laravel login showing password and id in url

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

i have created a login in laravel, actually am new to laravel, the website is already made in laravel and i have tried to add login and register in that, the login in welcome.blade.php is like below:

```html
<?php
$username = "";
$errors = array();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test');

$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM registers WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }}

?>
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
    
    
    <div style="width: 300px;">    
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  >
    </div>
    
        <br>
        <div style="width: 300px;"> 
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" >
        </div>
    <br>
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="login_user">Login</button>
   
    
  </form>
<?php if (isset($_GET['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM registers WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}?>
```

whenever i am trying to log in, it doesnt log in and instead reloads the same page and shows the entered password and username in the url like below

> http://demo.website/teia/members/?username=test&password=testing&login_user=

can anyone please tell me whats wrong in my code

Comment: This is core PHP code not a laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong method in your form. `GET` method always generates URI with input data, which is really huge vulnerability when doing something with data, such as user personal info. GET is used to request data from a specified resource, and the query string  is sent in the URL of a GET request.

Some other notes on GET requests:

- GET requests can be cached
- GET requests remain in the browser history
- GET requests can be bookmarked
- **GET requests should never be used when dealing with sensitive data**
- GET requests have length restrictions

To prevent this from happening, use POST method. POST is used to send data to a server. The data sent to the server with POST is stored in the request body of the HTTP request, instead of storing it in the URI, which is much safer.

Some other notes on POST requests:

- POST requests are never cached
- POST requests do not remain in the browser history
- POST requests cannot be bookmarked
- POST requests have no restrictions on data length

Change your form to this:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

Reference: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

EDIT: Don't forget to change your route to POST as well.

Comment: i used post earlier, but it was showing post not supported, i should use get, thats why i used get

Comment: i have changed the route also to post, still its showing post not supported

Comment: Can you edit your question and include your route. Also run `php artisan route:list` in your console,  and paste the output of your login route.

Answer (score 2):

At https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication

You can find a workflow used to create laravel login/registration.

Laravel ships with authentication/login/logout, you will not need to code this yourself!

Comment: i didnt understand, so how should i change my code?

Comment: Well, when in your console. this command: "php artisan make:auth"
WIll make a registration page + login page it will take care of everything including the databases.

Comment: This website has a basic laravel video tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018 It covers all the basics, its also made by the laravel team i believe

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is you are using form method as "get". It should be "post". Otherwise, the data you inserted will be shown in URL.

Secondly, the action of form is empty. That is why it is reloading the same page.

To solve this problem, you should dig a bit deeper. You should define one action URL for the form and define that in `routes/web.php` . 
Then it should be handled by a controller. You should make one controller and name it something like LoginController.php . 
Then the logic of handling the user authentication should be stored there.

Also, laravel has a boilerplate staff to make authentication a bit easier. If you like you should go through this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication).

Answer (score 0):

You are using form method GET instead of POST that's y the input values are showing in URL also convert the lines below

```
php if (isset($_GET['login_user'])) {
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['password']);
```

to

```
 php if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
```